# AWS Blazing text supervised hyperparameter not logging objective metric

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I am running a Hyperparameter tuning job using Sagemakers built in training image for Blazing text (blazingtext:latest) however when my jobs complete they only log out #train accuracy:

```
...
06:00:36 ##### Alpha: 0.0000 Progress: 100.00% Million Words/sec: 0.00 #####
06:13:19 Training finished.
06:13:19 Average throughput in Million words/sec: 0.00
06:13:19 Total training time in seconds: 1888.88
06:13:19 #train_accuracy: 0.4103
06:13:19 Number of train examples: 55783
```

The Hyperparameter job does not allow for me to pick #train_accuracy as an objective metric, only "validation:accuracy" or train:mean_rho appear in the dropdown.
[image: Objective metric]

After the job completes under "Best training job" tab I see:

> Best training job summary data is available when you have completed training jobs that are emiting metrics.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you provided a validation data channel? If not, then there is nothing to be output for "validation:accuracy".

Comment: That was the problem...knew it had to be something stupid. Thank you @NewIsAlwaysBetter

Answer (score 0):

Ensure there is a validation channel in addition to the "train" channel :

[image: validation image]